# removing an element from a linked list in python

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if any of you could give me a walk through on how to remove an element from a linked list in python, I'm not asking for code but just kinda a pseudo algorithm in english. for example I have the linked list of 
1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 and I want to remove one of the 2's how would i do that? I thought of traversing through the linked list, checking to see if the data of one of the nodes is equal to the data of the node after it, if it is remove it. But I'm having trouble on the removing part. Thanks!

Comment: `node.next = node.next.next`

Comment: so it would be node['next'] = node['next']['next'] ?

Comment: Quite possibly. It depends much on how it is implemented.

Comment: whenever I try it, it seems to remove everything up till the last element of the linked list... Weird

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the element, all you need to do is change the `pointer`. For example, you want the *previous element* of the node you want to delete to point to the element *after the element* you want to delete:

`node` is what you want to delete

```
node.parent.next = node.next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain two pointers

1. One is to check whether the current node's data is same as the value to be deleted
2. The other pointer is to keep the reference of the previous node to the current node. This is required because when you delete the current node, the current node's next one needs to be pointed to the current node's previous one.

Here is the code to do the same in python:

```
def remove(self, val):
    if self.head == val:
        self.head = self.head.next
        return

    tmp = self.head.next
    tmp_prev = self.head

    while tmp.next is not None:
        if tmp.data == val:
             tmp_prev.next = tmp.next
        tmp = tmp.next
        tmp_prev = tmp.next

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "delete" the node, just "skip" it.  That is, change Node1's *next* member to the second Node2.

Edit your question if you would like specific code examples (which are the norm for this site).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`if element.next.value == element.value:
    element.next = element.next.next`

Just be carefull to free the memory if you are programing this in C/C++ or other language that does not have GC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement list-like container with fast appends and pops on either end I highly recommend deque module from containers library https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove an element from the linked list, using index, you may do this like that:

```
def remove(self, index):
    cur_node = self.head
    cur_index = 0

    if cur_node is None:
        if index == 0:
            self.head = cur_node.next
            self.length -= 1
            return

    while cur_node is not None:
        if cur_index == index:
            break
        prev = cur_node
        cur_node = cur_node.next
        cur_index += 1

    if cur_node == None:
        return

    prev.next = cur_node.next
    cur_node = None
    self.length -= 1
```